# Implicit function theorem on dense subset

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and we are given a differentiable function
$$\Psi: U \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, \quad (x, A) \mapsto \Psi(x,A)$$ with $m>n$.

We further assume that there is an open dense subset $V \subset U$ such that
$$\forall x \in V \ \exists A \in \mathbb{R}^m: \quad \Psi(x,A)=0$$

By the implicit function theorem we know that $\forall x \in V$ exists an open neighbourhood $U_x \subset U$ where $A_{U_x}: U_x \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable function and $\Psi(x,A_{U_x}(x))=0$ as long as the Jacobian at $x$ is surjective.

---

**My question is the following:** Can we "patch" all the functions $A_{U_x}$ together to get a differentiable function on U, $A:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ such that in each open neighbourhood $U_x$ it holds $A|_{U_x}=A_{U_x}$?

---

Since $V$ is dense in $U$ I assume it is possible but I cannot come up with a proof.

Comment: If you write $\Psi:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^m$, to also write $(x,A)\mapsto\Psi(x,A)$ adds no information

Comment: May we assume you intended $\Psi:U\times\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^m$?

Comment: This question is also ill posed because we do *not* know $\forall x\in V$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U_x\subseteq V$ ... etc. because $V$ itself should be open for the implicit function theorem to kick in (counterexample would be $V=\Bbb Q^n\cap U$)

Comment: $V$ is irrelevant here anyway, since $\Psi(x,A)=0$ on $U$ as well, because of density. And then proper condition is "$U_x\subseteq U$", and we can get rid of $V$.

Comment: And of course it is not always possible to glue such functions. If $\Psi$ is constant zero, then each $A_{U_x}$ can be literally anything. But some $U_x$ have to intersect, and thus corresponding $A_{U_x}$ would have to coincide on the intersection.

Comment: @freakish I edited the question. Does it work if I additionally assume that $\Psi$ is invaraint under the flow of a differentiable vector field $\dot{x}=F(x)$. I.e. that $\Psi(x(t),A)=0 \quad \forall t \quad \forall x \in U$? Isn't this enough to glue $A$ together also for initially non-overlapping $U_x$?

Comment: @NicAG what do you mean by "non-overlapping $U_x$"? It is impossible to make such choice, some have to overlap. In particular because each $U_x$ contains some other point $y$ for which we consider $U_y$. Also doesn't $\Psi$ being constant zero still work?

Comment: But of course if you can pick a non-overlapping subfamily of all $U_x$ then this means that $U$ is the disjoint of them, and then you can glue them together. Regardless of what $A_{U_x}$ are. But as I said there is no guarantee that such subfamily exists. In particular if $U$ is connected then this would imply that $U=U_x$ for a single $x$. Which is kind of trivial situation.

Comment: So if $U$ is connected and we have $\Psi(x,A)=0 \quad \forall x \in U$. Can we generally claim that there is a differentiable function $A:U \mathbb{R}^m$ with $\Psi(x,A(x))=0 \quad \forall x \in U$. Given that the jacobian of $\Psi$ is surjective on the dense subset $V \subset U$?

Comment: When you say "$\forall x \in V: \  \Psi(x,A)=0$, what is $A$? There is no vector $A$ established at this point. Did you mean $\forall A\forall x \in V: \ \Psi(x,A)=0$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I mean that $\forall x \in V \exists A: \Psi(x,A)=0$

Comment: Then you should say so in the post.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I edited the question